# ffmpeg and php - generating thumbnail

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I've never used ffmpeg before, but it seemed rather straight forward. I already have a script that handles the uploaded file and stores all of the relative data into the database, but I'm not able to generate a thumbnail. I don't get an error either, I even checked the error_log on the server and there was nothing. The command I'm trying to use is:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i files/clipcanvas_14348_offline.mp4 -r 1 -s 1024x576 -f image2 -vframes 1 files/thumb_test.jpg");
```

I will change the static file names with variables once I get it working because the videos that will be thumbnailed are uploaded through a form.

I tried using the solution from this page:

[ffmpeg Getting image or thumbnail from video error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178735/ffmpeg-getting-image-or-thumbnail-from-video-error)

But I'm not having any luck. Could it somehow be possible it's because it's on a sub domain?

Comment: Does running the `ffmpeg` command manually successfully result in an image output?

Comment: I don't have `ffmpeg` installed locally. I'm just trying to run it on hostgator.com I made sure it was installed by echoing `phpinfo()` and I verified the path to `ffmpeg` via their website. Also, the mp4 file does exist.

Comment: Ok, so I installed `ffmpeg` locally and then ran the same command in the terminal and it worked perfectly. Could it be the path then? What is the path in the command relative to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working.

It turned out it was some sort of restriction/codec/outdated ffmpeg issue. I forced that mp4 to be an avi and it worked fine. That doesn't explain why it worked locally. My only guesses are that I'm on a mac at work and mp4's are native to mac's (the server is Linux) or the version of ffmpeg that I'm using is newer and offers more supported file types.

Either way, hopefully this will help out other people who run into the same problem.

Comment: If you included the complete `ffmpeg` console output the issue or cause might be obvious.

Comment: Well, locally it worked just fine. It was when I posted it online that it didn't work and it's a VPS through hostgator. I don't have access to where ffmpeg is. I can't even see the real version number using `phpinfo()`. Is there a ffmpeg equivalent of `var_dump()` that I can use?